# Defining new ActiveXObject returns just "Error"

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, dll, activex

I made a class library project and got a DLL from it and made sure all functions to be ComVisible(true) with unique GUID different from the one in assembly info and checked the "Register for COM interop" in project properties.

when using it with windows form application it works great but once i am usnig it with web application through ActiveX i receive the word "Error" with no other useful information about what is really happening.

I tried to re-register the DLL using regasm on another PC but still the same problem also checked if it's registered in the regedit and every thing was normal.

Also checked the security tab in the IE and the site i am developing is added to the trusted sites and all ActiveX security settings are enabled.

Is there any way I could know the real error or what should i do in this case ?

Note: i have another ActiveX objects in the same site all is working fine and i am using IE11 - Windows 10 64-bit with VS2015.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools or set debugger to debug your code, also you could use try catch statement to collect the log information, then, get the details error message.

Comment: The "ERROR" word i get, i get it from the console and debugger of the developer tools. Also i am using try and catch statements to make sure where the error happend but always and what ever i do i am getting the "Error" word. @Zhi